# uiButton should always be as top view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, uislider

i have a UIView UIImageview UIButton and UISlider added as subview to UIView

example:

[view addsubview:uiImageview_obj];
[view addsubview:uiButtonview_obj];
[view addsubview:uiSliderview_obj];

When i zoom the uiimageview_obj, it covers uislider and uibutton also, hence i cannot use uislider and uibutton when i zoom the image. So please tell me how to make uislider and uibutton to be always on top?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:

```
[view bringSubviewToFront:uiButtonview_obj]];
[view bringSubviewToFront:uiSliderview_obj]];
```

You could also do this by ordering your addSubview calls properly, but I think it's best to make this explicit behaviour in the code.